# SVG stacking in Chrome with radialGradient Element does not work properly

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg, stack, gradient

I'll try to use a SVG-Stack to display icons. However if I include them the into my HTML-Page the radialGradient-Element isn't displayed in Chrome when I include the icons external (
`<svg><use href="icons.svg#shape-green" /></svg>`). But using the same SVG-Code inline works.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
    <style>
        .svgIcon { width: 200px; height: 200px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>SVG Test</h1>
    
    <hr><h2>use href</h2>
    <svg class="svgIcon"><use href="icons.svg#shape-green"><title>Green</title></use></svg>

    <hr><h2>inline</h2> 
    <svg 
        class="svgIcon" 
        version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
        viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background="new 0 0 200 200" 
        xml:space="preserve">
        <defs>
            <radialGradient id="path2597radialGradient" cx="50.0736" cy="338.8645" r="40.2618" fx="57.261" fy="343.9495" gradientTransform="matrix(-9.176143e-03 -1.9189 1.8714 -8.948554e-03 -553.385 182.0688)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#C5FF89"/>
                <stop  offset="0.4371" style="stop-color:#81CB31"/>
                <stop  offset="0.6741" style="stop-color:#5AAE00"/>
            </radialGradient>
        </defs>
        
        <symbol viewBox="0 0 200 200" id="shape-green">
            <rect fill="#2E2E2E" width="200" height="200"/>
            <g>
                <rect x="25" y="25" fill="#2E2E2E" width="150" height="150"/>
                <path                   
                    fill="#FF0000" 
                    d="M101.3,36.3c35.2,0,63.7,28.5,63.7,63.6c0,35.2-28.5,63.7-63.6,63.7h-0.1c-35.2,0-63.7-28.5-63.7-63.6C37.5,64.9,66.1,36.3,101.3,36.3L101.3,36.3z"/>
                    
                <path 
                    fill="url(#path2597radialGradient)" 
                    d="M101.3,36.3c35.2,0,63.7,28.5,63.7,63.6c0,35.2-28.5,63.7-63.6,63.7h-0.1c-35.2,0-63.7-28.5-63.7-63.6C37.5,64.9,66.1,36.3,101.3,36.3L101.3,36.3z"
                />
            </g>
        </symbol>       

        <use href="#shape-green" />
    </svg>
    
</body>
</html>
```

icons.svg

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background="new 0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve">
     <defs>
        <radialGradient id="path2597radialGradient" cx="50.0736" cy="338.8645" r="40.2618" fx="57.261" fy="343.9495" gradientTransform="matrix(-9.176143e-03 -1.9189 1.8714 -8.948554e-03 -553.385 182.0688)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#C5FF89"/>
            <stop  offset="0.4371" style="stop-color:#81CB31"/>
            <stop  offset="0.6741" style="stop-color:#5AAE00"/>
        </radialGradient>
     </defs>
     <style>
        .stack_icon { display:none }
        .stack_icon:target { display:inline }
     </style>
        
        <symbol viewBox="0 0 200 200" id="shape-green">
            <rect fill="#2E2E2E" width="200" height="200"/>
            <g>
                <rect x="25" y="25" fill="#2E2E2E" width="150" height="150"/>
                <path                   
                    fill="#FF0000" 
                    d="M101.3,36.3c35.2,0,63.7,28.5,63.7,63.6c0,35.2-28.5,63.7-63.6,63.7h-0.1c-35.2,0-63.7-28.5-63.7-63.6C37.5,64.9,66.1,36.3,101.3,36.3L101.3,36.3z"/>
                    
                <path 
                    fill="url(#path2597radialGradient)" 
                    d="M101.3,36.3c35.2,0,63.7,28.5,63.7,63.6c0,35.2-28.5,63.7-63.6,63.7h-0.1c-35.2,0-63.7-28.5-63.7-63.6C37.5,64.9,66.1,36.3,101.3,36.3L101.3,36.3z"
                />
            </g>
        </symbol>   
</svg>
```

The SVG includes circels. One circle in the background with a red color and on top a green circle with a radialGradient. Only the green circle should be shown.

Demopage:
https://1628935.playcode.io/
https://playcode.io/1628935

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: Chrome allows [certain elements](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/main/third_party/blink/renderer/core/svg/svg_use_element.cc#L274) to be in a <use> instance and gradients aren't one of them.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=751733